# How do I create a new column filled with the results of a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column that is VARCHAR2 and the string inlcudes a date and time. I have extracted the date and now wish to populate a new column solely with the date and time.

So far I have:

```
alter table t
add cb_time
as
select substr(t.notes, 24, INSTR(t.notes, 'for')-1)
from Mytable t
```

this results in error ORA 2000 - missing ( keyword

Comment: Create the column with alter table, then update it with new values

Comment: How about a virtual column? See my answer.

Comment: thanks lalit this seems like the best solution but it doesnt like the format, it says it is missing a ')'

Comment: Sorry, one closing brace is missing in the end. There should be 3 closing braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on 11g, and as you say that both columns are in same table. I would suggest, do not add a static column, rather add a **virtual column**.

So, you need not worry about the **insert** too. Oracle would give you the computed value without actually storing it.

Just add the virtual column as -

**EDIT** A closing brace was missing in the end.

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD
       column_name GENERATED ALWAYS AS     (to_date(substr(t.notes, 24, INSTR(t.notes, 'for')-1))) VIRTUAL;
```

**NOTE** You need to be cautious though. The virtual column would only be able to work if the **expression** is correctly evaluated. In this case, if the **datetime literal** is malformed, then the virtual column would fail. Either make sure that all the values in your base column have proper format of datetime literal.

Comment: this is giving me an error, ora-02000: missing ) keyword   it has 4x ( and only 3 x ) but i cannot see where the extra ) is required

Comment: Sorry, one closing brace is missing in the end. There should be 3 closing braces. Fixed it, please try now.

Comment: that has worked but i am getting an error, my date format is 08/01/2015 13:30   which is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm  The error is saying invalid month, it is expecting Jan or January in place of 01, how do i change the mask?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are only concerned with the values with the format you mentioned in above comment.

Comment: yes all of the relevant entries will be in that format

Comment: Ok, so tweak the query. `08/01/2015 13:30` have total 16 characaters. So tweak the `substr` query to suffice it. I hope it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to create `CB_TIME` as a virtual column. To do soan ALTER TABLE similar to the following is used:

```
ALTER TABLE T
  ADD CB_TIME DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS
        (TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t.notes, 24, INSTR(t.notes, 'for')-1))) VIRTUAL;
```

Because virtual columns can't be INSERTed or UPDATEed, doing it this way means that the `NOTES` field must always contain a valid date string.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: not all rows will contain a valid date string, will that mean that a virtual column will not work?

Comment: It means that for those rows where no date is present in the string there won't be a value for `CB_TIME`. If that's not what you want then you should add a "real" column and perform the necessary UPDATE. Best of luck.

Comment: thank you Bob, i dont need a value in those fields so this should be fine, appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

You should do it as two separate operations.

```
alter table t add cb_time date;

update t set cb_time = to_date(substr(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first add the column with `ALTER TABLE` and then issue an `UPDATE`:

```
ALTER TABLE t
  ADD cb_time DATE;

UPDATE t
   SET cb_time = SUBSTR(t.notes, 24, INSTR(t.notes, 'for')-1);
```

But you should also convert the value to a `DATE` at the same time:

```
UPDATE t
   SET cb_time = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t.notes, 24, INSTR(t.notes, 'for')-1));
```

It might even be a good idea to make sure that the value in `t.notes` contains a date (maybe using regex) so you don't get an error when updating.

Comment: Just a note on your suggestion, regular expressions are not really efficient. Even in the latest 12c versions, regexp are CPU intensive operations. I prefer regexp only when they seem to the only option.

Comment: True, another alternative might be to use a trigger to populate on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` and just trap the error raise by `TO_DATE()` in the event the string doesn't contain a `DATE`

Comment: Still not as efficient as compared to have a data model which follows normalization and data validation rules. But yes, when struggling with a bad design, a phrase goes like this *"when you are trapped inside a hole, stop digging first"* ;-)

Comment: No kidding ... but sometimes we have to work with what we're given rather than what we would like to have.

Comment: Yup, agreed. So I added the phrase in my above comment. In my experience, while consulting for clients having legacy systems, I have least options to do work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
alter table t add cb_time date;
update t set cb_time = to_date(substr(t.notes, 24, INSTR(t.notes, 'for')-1);
```